# Entity framework - how to insert into many to many table with additional properties?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have 2 entities.

Project entity

```
[Table("Project")]
public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        Participants = new List<Participation>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(225)]
    [Index(IsUnique=true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ProjectVisibility Visibility { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Participation> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

And UserProfile entity

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Participation> Participations { get; set; }


}
```

Each User can participate in a project with different access levels to this project, so in the linking table I store not only 2 IDs, but also - 3rd property for the access level. (Accesibility is just an enumeration with 1/2/3/4 available values) Here it is :

```
 [Table("Participations")]
public class Participation
{
    public virtual Project ProjectReference { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserReference { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public Accessibility AccessLevel { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to create a new Project and assign the current user as the owner of the project, however I keep getting different kind of errors. Here is my 'CreateProject' code :

```
public void CreateProject(Project model, UserProfile owner)
    {
        var participation = new Participation { ProjectReference = model, UserReference = owner, AccessLevel = Accessibility.Owner };
        Participations.Add(participation);
        Projects.Add(model);
        SaveChanges();
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this please :)  ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add description of errors you have

Answer (score 1):

Add foreign key attributes to inform EF about relations between keys and navigation properties:

```
[Table("Participations")]
public class Participation
{
    [ForeignKey("ProjectID")]
    public virtual Project ProjectReference { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual UserProfile UserReference { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public Accessibility AccessLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Also make sure that you have [attached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) project and user to current context. Otherwise EF will add them with same state as root participation entity, i.e. with `Added` state. And EF will treat all entities as newly added and it will try to insert them to database.

Comment: I get an error "[System.InvalidOperationException] = {"An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."}" on the line where I add the participation to the Participations DbSet

Comment: @ShtiliyanUzunov you have two different contexts. It's not allowed to have entity attached to several contexts. Make sure you use single context instance